# how to access form value in ts component - angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I know so many answer are available but I install angular 6 version now form value is not submitted!
I add console screen shot blow 
any one tell me where I am wrong.
HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" class="jumbotron">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fName" ngModel>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lName" ngModel>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  arr: any[]=[];    
  onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
    this.arr = form.value
    console.log('array', this.arr);
    console.log('value', form.value);
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are getting value if you expand the object you will get the data

Comment: can you write syntax here

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You can also do something like this `console.log('array', this.arr | json);` to see what the object looks like

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1rrt3 i am printing the form data using json pipe

Comment: I expect to value which are input form user but here it shows object

Comment: you can try ```console.log(JSON.stringify(this.arr))```.

Comment: Basically what i said @Chellappan lol

Comment: @Chellappan that good but how to see in console after click add button

Comment: currently its showing the data in console check your console

Answer (score 1):

To see the values of the objects you can json prettifier it like so:

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm ) {
    this.arr = form.value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify( this.arr));
    console.log(JSON.stringify( form.value));
   }
```

This will take a JSON object string and return it pretty-printed/formatted